# Getting weights and biases from a CNN model and saving them into csv file

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have recently built a CNN model for image classification for cifar 10. The model works but i am having trouble to generate weights and biases for each trainable layers (convolution and dense layers) . Below is the code part for adding the layers in building the model and then loading it

```
  from __future__ import print_function

import keras
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, AveragePooling2D
from keras.utils.data_utils import Sequence
import os
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np



def square(x):
 return x * x;

batch_size = 64
num_classes = 10
epochs = 500
num_predictions = 20
save_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'saved_models')
model_name = 'cifar_model2.h5'

 # The data, split between train and test sets:
 (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

  x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
  x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
  x_train = np.round(x_train/32)/8
  x_test = np.round(x_test/32)/8
  print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
  print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
  print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

  y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
  y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same',
             input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
  model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Conv2D(83, (3, 3)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.25))
  model.add(Activation(square))

  model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Conv2D(130, (5, 5), padding='same'))
  model.add(Activation(square))
  model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.25))

  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(512))
  model.add(Dense(num_classes))
  model.add(Activation('softmax'))

  opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(amsgrad=True, decay=0.0001, lr = 0.001)

  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])


  print('Using real-time data augmentation.')
  datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      featurewise_center=False,  
      samplewise_center=False,  
      featurewise_std_normalization=False,
      samplewise_std_normalization=False, 
      zca_whitening=False,  
      zca_epsilon=1e-06,  
      rotation_range=0,  
      width_shift_range=0.1,
      height_shift_range=0.1,
      shear_range=0.,
      zoom_range=0., 
      channel_shift_range=0., 
      fill_mode='nearest',
      cval=0.,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      vertical_flip=False, 
      rescale=None,
      preprocessing_function=None,
      data_format=None,
      validation_split=0.0)
 if not os.path.isdir(save_dir):
     os.makedirs(save_dir)
 model_path = os.path.join(save_dir, model_name)
 checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_path, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0,    
 save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=10)
 callback_list=[checkpoint]
 datagen.fit(x_train)
 model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size), 
 callbacks=callback_list,steps_per_epoch=len(x_train)/batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), workers=4)

# Save 
 model.save(model_path)
 print('Saved trained model at %s ' % model_path)

 scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1)
 print('Test loss:', scores[0])
 print('Test accuracy:', scores[1])


from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import load_model
save_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'saved_models')
model_name = 'cifar_model2.h5'
model_path = os.path.join(save_dir, model_name)
def square(x):
   return x * x;
# load model
model = load_model(model_path, custom_objects={'square': square})]
```

Next I enter the code:

```
model.summary()
```

for viewing all the layers with parameters(trainable layers) . And it shows the layers :

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 128)       3584      
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_4 (Average (None, 16, 16, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 83)        95699     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 14, 14, 83)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 14, 14, 83)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_5 (Average (None, 7, 7, 83)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 7, 7, 130)         269880    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 7, 7, 130)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_6 (Average (None, 3, 3, 130)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 3, 3, 130)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 1170)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 512)               599552    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 10)                5130      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 10)                0         
=================================================================
```

Total params: 973,845
Trainable params: 973,845
Non-trainable params: 0

Now the question is how do i get the weights and biases of each layer and then save them in a 'csv' file?.I have just managed to  obtain the weights and biases of a single layer using the code below:

```
 from numpy import loadtxt
 from keras.models import load_model
 from keras.engine import InputLayer

 output_center=2
 input_kernel_range = range(0,10)
 input_shape=[14,14,83]
 input_maps = input_shape[2]
 model_ = Sequential()
 model_.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),input_shape=[14,14,83]))
 model_.add(Conv2D(130, (5, 5), padding='same'))
 model_.layers[1].set_weights(model.layers[6].get_weights())
 test = np.zeros(input_shape)[np.newaxis,...]
 bias = model_.predict(test)[0,output_center,output_center,:]
 A = 0
for c in range(0, input_maps):
   for y in input_kernel_range:
      for x in input_kernel_range:
         test = np.zeros(input_shape)[np.newaxis,...]
         test[0,x,y,c]=1
         prediction = model_.predict(test)
         d = prediction[0,output_center,output_center,:] - bias
         if (isinstance(A, int)):
            A = d
        else:
            A = np.c_[A, d]
A.tofile("weights.csv", sep=',')
bias.tofile("bias.csv", sep=',')
```

This is just for only one layer. Like I said,I am trying to get the weights and biases and save it in 'csv' like this for all the convolution  and dense layers .Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't it be more convenient if you use inbuilt method ```model.save_weights(filepath)```? It will be easier to load these weights again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my purpose is to save the weights and biases of each convolution and dense layers separately like for example 'weights.csv' and 'bias.csv' for conv layer 1 , 'weights2.csv' and 'bias2.csv' for conv 2nd layer or a dense layer , like this for all convolutional and dense layers in the model  . Want the weights and biases for for each layer in .csv files .

Answer (score 1):

To get weights and biases for Conv2D and Dense layers you can do following:

```
wt = open('weights.csv', 'w')
bs = open('biases.csv', 'w')
for idx,i in enumerate(model.layers):
  if(isinstance(i, Conv2D) or isinstance(i, Dense)):
    weights = i.get_weights()[0]
    biases = i.get_weights()[1]
    weights = weights.flatten()
    biases = biases.flatten()
    print(weights.shape, biases.shape)
    wt.write(','.join(map(str,weights.tolist()))+"\n")
    bs.write(','.join(map(str,biases.tolist()))+"\n")
    #np.savetxt("weight" + str(idx)+".csv" , weights , fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
    #np.savetxt("bias" + str(idx) +".csv" , biases , fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
```

You can keep track of original shapes of layers also, since it is flattened to store in CSV. That'll help you if you want to load these weights again in future.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but will it save the weights and biases of all the layers in one single 'weight.csv' and 'bias.csv' file?

Comment: This loop is iterating through all layers, so for each layer you will get weights and biases. You can save that in format you want, either separately or combined.

Comment: Can you also add the part where i would save the weights and biases for each layer ,i.e for example weights or bias for 'one layer(conv or dense)' in one 'weights.csv' or 'bias.csv' file inside or outside the loop?.Like,  for conv2d_5  layer, separate weights.csv and bias.csv files using the loop or outside it. It'll be again of huge help.

Comment: Thanks a lot till now, i'll see if i can successfully implement the code. I'll let you know in the comments if i face any more errors regarding this. Thanks again :)

Comment: Your code works perfectly :). But jst one other thing is that in the weights.csv and bias.csv , the weights and biases come in a single column( for a single layer i presume) and different rows. If i were to put biases or weights in the files to single rows and different columns for a layer i.e for a particular bias.csv or weights.csv file what could be done ?                                                                   You were an immense help till now, thanks again

Comment: well Sir, any solution to my recent problem?  It'll solve my last hurdle in building a successful cnn model like this for my own dataset in my thesis work.

Comment: @IshfaqueQamarKhilji modified code will save weights and biases in two files layer by layer.

Comment: @IshfaqueQamarKhilji in that case you can move _wt_ and _bs_ file pointers inside loop and add appropriate index in file name string.

Comment: what i meant was transpose the one column that were there in each bias.csv and columns in weights.csv files from the previous code into single rows . Eg.for a bias file for a layer 'bias0.csv' the biases were like this:                                                                         
0.003184717
-0.001100331
-0.000326951
which i wanted being  0.003184717, -0.001100331,-0.000326951.Each  of the bias .csv and weights.csv had it in columns from your previous code to which i wanted in single rows. Thanks again for all the help till now.

Comment: Hi you can refer: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reading-and-writing-csv-file-using-python on how to read and write CSV